# Plugin for vuex doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-resource

**My goal:**

I wont to create plugin that will setup header with token for all requests.

**Problem:**

Plugin doesn't work.

**Comments:**

Plugin should be added to the storage module. (May be it matters something in this case. I don't know)

**Plugin code:**

```
export default function(store){
    store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {

        if(mutation.type === "GetToken"){

            console.log('TOKEN: ' + state.token);

            Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {

                request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +state.token);
                next();

            });

        }

    });
}
```

**storage code:**

```
import AuthenticationPlugin from "../plugins/authorization"
export default {

    namespaced: true,

    plugins: [AuthenticationPlugin],

    state:{
        token: null,
        email: null,
        signinResponse:{
            ok:         null,
            status:     null,
            statusText: null,
            url:        null,
            data:       null,
        },
    },

    getters:{
        userToken(state){
            return state.token;
        },
        userSigninResponseOk(state){
            return state.signinResponse.ok;
        },
        userSigninResponseStatus(state){
            return state.signinResponse.status;
        },
        userSigninResponseStatusText(state){
            return state.signinResponse.statusText;
        },
        userSigninResponseUrl(state){
            return state.signinResponse.url;
        },
        userSigninResponseData(state){
            return state.signinResponse.data;
        },
    },

    mutations:{
        GetToken(state, credentials){

            let c = credentials;
            let s = state;

            s.email       = c.email;

            Vue.http.post('api/admin/signin', {
                'email':    c.email ,
                'password': c.password,
            }).then(response=>{

                let r = response,
                    d = r.data,
                    s = state,
                    sr= s.signinResponse;

                s.token       = d.hasOwnProperty('token') ? d.token : null;
                sr.ok         = r.ok;
                sr.status     = r.status;
                sr.statusText = r.statusText;
                sr.url        = r.url;
                sr.data       = r.data;

            }, response=>{

                let r = response,
                    d = r.data,
                    s = state,
                    sr= s.signinResponse;

                sr.token      = null;
                sr.ok         = r.ok;
                sr.status     = r.status;
                sr.statusText = r.statusText;
                sr.url        = r.url;
                sr.data       = r.data;

            });

        }
    },

    actions:{
        GetToken(context, credentials){
            context.commit('GetToken', credentials);
        }
    },

}
```

Comment: Where is the actual error?

Comment: @FrankProvost I don't know were is error. I just know that it doesn't work. IDE console was is empty, Browser console was empty too. When I placed  console.log() function to plugin just to check was plugin called or not, I didn't get any massage from this function in my browser console.

Comment: @FrankProvost  Actually I understood that idea of storing token in vuex storage was wrong. Because, if user will reload browser page, token will be deleted, and he will have to login again. But  if we will abstract from understanding of wrong conception, I think plugin must work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want listen to module mutations, you must call mutation with module register name. And i don't know the plugin can inject at module, so i think plugin should inject to in store.js file

My

```
import ObservePlugin from "./ObservePlugin";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
...
    modules: {
        'sampleModule': SampleModule
    }
    plugins :[
        ObservePlugin
    ]
})
```

Subscribe for namespaced module mutation:

```
store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    if(mutation.type === 'sampleModule/mutationName') {
        console.log(mutation)
    }
})
```